# Importing nodes into Neo4j using batch importer with automatic indexing

Tags: java, neo4j

I have imported nodes using [jdbc importer](https://github.com/dmontag/neo4j-import) but am unable to figure out auto_index support. How do I get auto indexing?

Answer (score 1):

The tool you link to does give instructions for indexing, but I've never used it and it doesn't seem to be up to date. I would recommend you use one of the importing tools listed [here](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/import). You can convert your comma separated file to tab separated and use [this batch importer](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) or one of the [neo4j-shell tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#import-data-into-your-neo4j-database-from-the-neo4j-shell-command), both of which support automatic indexing.

If you want to use a JDBC driver, for instance with some data transfer tool like Pentaho Kettle, there are instructions and links on the Neo4j import page, first link above.

I know from another question that you use regular expressions heavily and it is possible that 'automatic index', which is a Lucene index, may be very good for that, since you can query the index with regexp directly. But if you want to index your nodes within their labels, the new type of index in 2.0, then you don't need to setup indexing before importing. You can create an index at any time and it is populated in the background. If that's what you want, you can read the documentation about working with indices from [Java API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-new-index.html) and [Cypher](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-schema-index.html).

Comment: i have MySQL tables those have millions of records i didn't find suitable jdbc  batch importer to create  nodes with automatic indexing